# How to set value and reset to initial when app is closed?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to set value in flutter as long the app is running and when the app is closed value reset to initial value?
For example, when you have a tab bar selected index I want it to keep the value when I navigate to a different page. So when I go back to the page with tabs The selected index is the one I set before.

Comment: perhaps the easiest way would be just set it to initial value upon the app is launched?

Answer (score 0):

```
Static int myPage=0//initial value;
```

set it use it forget it

Comment: only declare is once at global level outside of any class